Cannot index into a null array- Power automate
I'm using power automate to return user profile data from AAD via graph api.
My calling graph api query
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/groupid/members?$select=displayName,city,department,businessPhones,jobTitle,officeLocation,mail,mobilePhone,createdDateTime&$top=2
Some users have the field businessPhones empty (See json below).
{
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
        "displayName": "DXu Po",
        "city": "Ondo",
        "department": "Design",
        "businessPhones": [
          "93625613000"
        ],
        "jobTitle": "Designer",
        "mail": "comradecom.au",
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "createdDateTime": "2019-09-18T05:54:26Z"
      }

I tried the below to check if the field is empty and if yes insert null
if(empty(items('Apply_to_each_2')?['businessPhones'][0]),'[]',null)

But still getting the same error.
Any ideas what i'm missing here.
Thanks in Advance

Based on above condition it's look like when businessPhones empty it's returning '[]' and when not empty it's returning null.
Based on your description your condition should look like something below
if(empty(items('Apply_to_each_2')?['businessPhones']?[0]),null,items('Apply_to_each_2')?['businessPhones']?[0])

added ? to avoid null error

Thanks Bharat. That did the trick not sure what i was thinking
